# How does the author concludes that $f^{-1} (V)$ can be written as the union of the open sets $U_x$?

Tags: general-topology

In the book of *General Topology* by Munkres, at page 105, it is given that

[image]

[image]

I understand that for arbitrary $x \in f^{-1} (V)$, we have $U_x \subseteq f^{-1} (V)$; however, how does the author concludes that 
**"$f^{-1} (V)$ can be written as the union of the open sets $U_x$"** ?

Comment: $x\in U_x\subseteq f^{-1}(V)$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown didn't get it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Each $U_x$ is open
- Each $U_x$ is contained in $f^{-1}(V)$ (in other words, $\bigcup_{x\in f^{-1}(V)}U_x\subseteq f^{-1}(V)$)
- Each point $x_0\in f^{-1}(V)$ is an element of $U_{x_0}$ (in other words, $f^{-1}(V)\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in f^{-1}(V)}U_x$)

Comment: Then for a fixed $x$, wouldn't we have $f^{-1} (V) = U_x$ ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas It could happen, sure. There is no reason it must happen, though (we never assumed that $U_x$ was as large as possible). If it did happen, would there be any problems? The issue here is that in just assuming (4), we have no way of knowing whether $U_x = f^{-1}(V)$ for that fixed $x$. So we have to collect all the $U_x$ and union them together.

Answer (score 1):

Just use that $x \in U_x \subseteq f^{-1}(V)$ for all $x \in f^{-1}(V)$.

$$f^{-1}(V)= \bigcup_{x \in f^{-1}(V)} \{x\} \subseteq\bigcup_{x \in f^{-1}(V)} U_x \subseteq \bigcup_{x \in f^{-1}(V)} f^{-1}(V) = f^{-1}(V)$$

We conclude $\displaystyle\bigcup_{x \in f^{-1}(V)} U_x = f^{-1}(V)$.